# Vertx code generation failed - Illegal type java.lang.String[] of kind ARRAY

Tags: java, vert.x

While compiling java code using vertx code generation, It failed throwing an error
Illegal type java.lang.String[] of kind ARRAY.

Here is the entity used in service.

```
@DataObject
public Word{
...

  @Type( type = "string-array" )
  @Column(columnDefinition = "ARRAY")
  @Size(min=1, max=10)
  private String[] examples = null;

...
}
```

Here is the stack trace when I run mvn compile,

> SEVERE: Could not generate element for xxx.Word: Illegal type
>   java.lang.String[] of kind ARRAY java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Illegal type java.lang.String[] of kind ARRAY
>           at io.vertx.codegen.type.TypeMirrorFactory.create(TypeMirrorFactory.java:68)
>           at io.vertx.codegen.type.TypeMirrorFactory.create(TypeMirrorFactory.java:43)
>           at io.vertx.codegen.DataObjectModel.processMethod(DataObjectModel.java:366)
>           at io.vertx.codegen.DataObjectModel.processMethods(DataObjectModel.java:352)
>           at io.vertx.codegen.DataObjectModel.traverse(DataObjectModel.java:227)
>           at io.vertx.codegen.DataObjectModel.process(DataObjectModel.java:163)
>           at io.vertx.codegen.CodeGen.getDataObjectModel(CodeGen.java:189)
>           at io.vertx.codegen.CodeGen.lambda$null$16(CodeGen.java:117)
>           at io.vertx.codegen.CodeGen$ModelEntry.getValue(CodeGen.java:223)

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data objects don't support arrays, so you need to use a `List<String>` as the types of the corresponding the getter/setter, the internal value can remain an array.